# how to concatenate values of a column if the other columns have the same value

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a query

```
SELECT
    cc.contact_id,
    cc.name,
    ct.name AS contact_type
FROM
    contacts AS c
    LEFT JOIN contact_companies AS cc ON c.contact_id = cc.contact_id
    LEFT JOIN contacts_to_types AS ctt ON cc.contact_id = ctt.contact_id
    LEFT JOIN contact_types AS ct ON ctt.contact_type_id = ct.contact_type_id
WHERE
     cc.name LIKE '%p%'
ORDER BY name, contact_id
```

which returns:

```
+------------+--------------------------------+--------------+
| contact_id | name                           | contact_type |
+------------+--------------------------------+--------------+
|        297 | Primary Properties Corporation | Supplier     |
|        297 | Primary Properties Corporation | Prospect     |
|        297 | Primary Properties Corporation | Customer     |
|        298 | San Miguel Corporation         | Prospect     |
|        301 | Sulpicio Lines                 | Supplier     |
+------------+--------------------------------+--------------+
```

when I would like it to return:

```
+------------+--------------------------------+------------------------------+
| contact_id | name                           | contact_type                 |
+------------+--------------------------------+------------------------------+
|        297 | Primary Properties Corporation | Supplier, Prospect, Customer |
|        298 | San Miguel Corporation         | Prospect                     |
|        301 | Sulpicio Lines                 | Supplier                     |
+------------+--------------------------------+------------------------------+
```

that is, I'd like it to combine the `contact_type` of 297.

Is this possible? Could someone please show me how? :)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) aggregate function

```
SELECT
    cc.contact_id,
    cc.name,
    GROUP_CONCAT(ct.name SEPARATOR ', ') AS contact_type
FROM
    contacts AS c
    LEFT JOIN contact_companies AS cc ON c.contact_id = cc.contact_id
    LEFT JOIN contacts_to_types AS ctt ON cc.contact_id = ctt.contact_id
    LEFT JOIN contact_types AS ct ON ctt.contact_type_id = ct.contact_type_id
WHERE
     cc.name LIKE '%p%'
GROUP BY cc.contact_id
ORDER BY name, contact_id
```